# Spring security Annotation expected to be inline constant

Tags: grails, spring-security

I get below error in grails when I try to define my String outside @Secured annotation.

I get following error
Role.USER' to be an inline constant of type java.lang.String not a property expression in @grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

```
class Role {
    final static String USER = "ROLE_USER"
    final static String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN"


    public final static String[] LOGINED_USER = [USER, ADMIN].asImmutable()

}
```

The below controller illustrate my issue..

```
class MyController {

    @Secured(["permitAll"]) //Works fine
    def action1() {
    }


    @Secured(LOGINED_USER) //Doesn't work
    def action2() {
    }

    @Secured([Role.ADMIN, Role.USER]) //Doesn't work
    def action3() {
    }


    @Secured(["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"]) //Works fine
    def action4() {
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286132/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-constant-to-an-annotation-in-groovy

I believe you can do it with:

`@Secured(value=Role.ADMIN)`

Comment: Nope.. same issue as before.

Comment: The issue is the groovy to java... as groovy make get and set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make USER and ADMIN constants public explicitly, add `public` modifier

```
public final static String USER = "ROLE_USER"
public final static String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN"
```

In that case Groovy will not use `geters` `setter` which is not allowed in annotations.

Comment: works flawlessly